# Inserting into Many-to-Many database?

Tags: c#, sql, many-to-many, relational-database

Guys I am trying to learn many-to-many relationship databases but I am having trouble in inserting data in the "link/junction" table.
This is what my database look like :
[image]

Now as my application is windows desktop application in C#, I have a simple Form in which I have 5 textboxes & a button, this is what it looks like :

[image]

Note : Image 2 - red represents the textbox name with .Text and blue represents the type of data I will be entering. EngineerID 1, 2 and 3 already exists in table `tblEngineer`.

Now on pressing add, I want to enter the value of `Date` & `Phone Number` in table `tblTicketDetail` and value of `EngineerID 1`, `EngineerID 2` and `EngineerID 3` in table `tblTicket_Engineer`. Table `tblEngineer` already has some rows in it.

Now if I was to enter only one EngineerID in tblTicket_Engineer, I would do this in click event of "Add" button :

```
        string statement = "INSERT INTO tblTicketDetail(IssueDate,Number) VALUES(@text1,@text2);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(statement))
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ST"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
        {

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text1", textBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text2", textBox2.Text);
                connection.Open();
                command.Connection = connection;
                ID = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                connection.Close();
        }

        string statement1 = "INSERT INTO tblTicket_Engineer(ID,EID) VALUES(@text1,@text3)";
        using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(statement1))
        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ST"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
        {

            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text1", ID);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text3", textBox3.Text);
            connection1.Open();
            command1.Connection = connection1;
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection1.Close();
        }
```

Look at the foreign keys in table `tblTicket_Engineer` and tell me if my foreign keys are correct.

[image]

What should I do to enter 3 rows at once in table `tblTicket_Engineer`? 
This is what I want to happen in `tblTicket_Engineer` when I press add button (For this image, values were entered manually)

[image]

Comment: From an SQL point of view, you should be inserting data to ticketdetail and engineer tables first before inserting to ticket_engineer.

Comment: `tblEngineer` already has some data, and I am inserting data first in `tblTicketDetail` and then upon the generated id, I am inserting data in `tblTicket_Engineer`

Comment: The bottom line is, if you've set up the ticket_engineer table properly, they'd be keys to the other two table. This means whatever you want to chuck in there better exist in the ticket and engineer tables first.

Comment: Yes, I know that is why from the first Insert query I am using SELECT SCOPE to get the value of identity column just generated and then I am inserting that value in the junction table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL`. Try something like this :

```
        string statement1 = @"INSERT INTO tblTicket_Engineer(TicketID,EngineerID) 
                        SELECT @ID,@EID1 UNION ALL
                        SELECT @ID,@EID2 UNION ALL
                        SELECT @ID,@EID3";
        using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(statement1))
        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ST"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
        {

            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", PID);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID1", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID2", comboBox2.SelectedValue);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID3", comboBox3.SelectedValue);
            connection1.Open();
            command1.Connection = connection1;
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection1.Close();
```